# Declaring generic type in a method that defines Class<?>

Tags: java, generics, jackson

What I am trying to do:

```
getMapType(String.class,String.class); //returns me a MapType of Map<String,String>
```

What I've tried:

```
public static <K extends Class<?>, V extends Class<?>> MapType getMapType(K keyClass, V valueClass) {
    return objectMapper.getTypeFactory().constructMapType(HashMap.class, keyClass,valueClass);
}
```

This gives me a warning when declaring K,V is extending the class.

```
The type parameter V should not be bounded by the final type Class<?>. Final types cannot be further extended
```

**I am aware** this means any class can't extend Class because its a final class. If I remove `extends Class<?>` the method constructMapType(...) will fail because of the type.
My question is how can I implement my method so I don't get this warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you may be looking for

```
public static <K, V> MapType getMapType(Class<K> keyClass, Class<V> valueClass){
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking at implementing something like

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;



public class HashMapExample {
    public static <K, V> Map<K,V> getMapType(Class<K> keyClass, Class<V> valueClass) {
        return new HashMap<>();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, String> mapType = HashMapExample.getMapType(String.class, String.class);


    }
}
```

Consider looking at some of the source code for the Collections class in java - it looks like the following

```
public static <K,V> Map<K,V> synchronizedMap(Map<K,V> m) {
        return new SynchronizedMap<>(m);
}
```

Comment: I think the goal is bit different, since it is not about constructing a `Map` instance, but creating `MapType`, which is a Jackson type representation needed for data-binding, letting Jackson know details of type to bind data to (or sometimes from).

Answer (score 0):

If the types `K` and `V` are not actually referred to in the method, you can simply use wildcards:

```
public static MapType getMapType(Class<?> keyClass, Class<?> valueClass) {
    return objectMapper.getTypeFactory().constructMapType(
        HashMap.class, keyClass, valueClass);
}
```